# Java code is seems to be ignored

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I have a problem with Java/HIBERNATE.

Here is some lines of code:

```
quickOrder.setResultUrl(resultUrl);
quickOrder.setStatus(QuickOrder.OrderedCampaignStatus.READY);
quickOrder.setPerformDate(DateTime.now());
em.merge(quickOrder)
```

In 99% cases it works fine. Everything is changed and written into a database. But I started to realize that sometimes the line

```
quickOrder.setStatus(QuickOrder.OrderedCampaignStatus.READY);
```

is seems to be ignored and the status isn't changed.
Everything else is written and merged, exclude this line.
What problem can it be?

Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "quick_orders")
public class QuickOrder {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private OrderedCampaign orderedCampaign;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bloggerId", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private WebUser blogger;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private OrderedCampaignStatus status;
```

Comment: what is your entity and how configured? (from @user2120275)

Comment: Check that the `status` field on whatever Hibernate entity `quickOrder` represents is not marked `updatable=false`

Comment: I added entity to the main question

Comment: Are you sure you don't happen to have 2 processes that concurrently are updating the same row?  I see no `@Version` to control optimistic locking, so it is certainly a possibility.

Comment: Naros, I am sure and I am using Pessimistic_Write locktype while working with the row in this java method.

Comment: Try to narrow down the scenarios in which this does happen. For example, does this happen only when you assign something to `status` from `null`? Or from something to `null`? Could you please post the declaration of `OrderedCampaignStatus`?